# Insert entries into a table with uniqueness check skipped

Tags: postgresql

I have this table which has some uniqueness constraints and when I do a particular insert statement I want make sure that uniqueness constraints are disabled and not enabled..
Is possible to disable the unique constrains defined for a table and then enable it again - or perhaps even better only for a particular query?

I am using postgres version 12

My tables are initially created without any uniqueness constrains but are altered to have an uniqueness constrain if it need to have one..

```
-- Create table with EntityId
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.{table_name}
    ({table_name}_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY);


-- Create table_registration
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.{table_name}_registration 
(
    entry_id bigint REFERENCES |entityName|({table_name}_id),
    row_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    valid tsrange,
    entry_name text,
    registration tsrange,
    registration_by varchar(255),
    |NewAttribute| |datatype|
);
```

Later are constrains added like this

```
ALTER TABLE {table_name}_registration 
DROP Constraint IF EXISTS {table_name}_{string.Join('_', listOfAttributes)}_key, 
ADD Constraint {table_name}_{string.Join('_', listOfAttributes)}_key UNIQUE({string.Join(',', listOfAttributes)});
```

Prior to doing this all uniqueness is dropped using this

```
-- Drop all uniqueness constraints
DO $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r in  SELECT
                conrelid::regclass,
                conname
            FROM
                pg_constraint
            WHERE
                contype IN ('u')
                AND connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
  LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I DROP CONSTRAINT %I', r.conrelid::text, r.conname::text);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

Comment: How do you imagine to re-enable a uniqueness constraint with non-unique values in the table?

Comment: Similar to when you remove a uniqueness constraint and then reinsert it - the constrain is only valid for new entries and not old ones.  

I could list uniqueness contrain for that particular table and drop them -  but then recreating them would be an issue as I am not sure I can get the constraint definition? 

@ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: Nope, a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` is absolute. It's implemented with a `UNIQUE` index and cover *all* rows. A partial index might work for you. But I'd need more details in the question. Start with your Postgres version and a basic table definition ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter added example on how I create table alter it to have uniqueness and how i prior to all this drop them and then alter each table to reinsert an uniqueness constraint

Comment: Are there clearly defined rules about which rows can "violate" the `UNIQUE` constraint, and does each row contain the necessary data to determine whether the constrant should be enforced? These are requirements to be able to partial `UNIQUE INDEX` as suggested by @ErwinBrandstetter. If not, you really can't use database-level constraints for this purpose. What does the regular table data look like, and what are the full values for the rows which need to violate the constraint?

Comment: What is not allowed is identical rows, but if someone want to make an entry with  where the uniqueness is being violated, it should be allowed, but the new entry need atleast one of its column to be different. @Timshel

And yes there is clearly defined which rows that can violate the unique -

Comment: It sounds like you need a `UNIQUE` constraint which covers all relevant rows. I note you have a `tsrange` in the base table; is this one of the columns that can identify a "different" row? If so, you might want to look at using the [`EXCLUDE` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) (a PostgreSQL extension associated with GIN/GiST indexes) rather than `UNIQUE`. This allows ensuring non-overlapping timestamps if that's a requirements.

Comment: @Timshel It is as you state -  when I  insert a new entry I make sure that the valid tsrange is not overlapping with the prior one... So both entries will be changed. 

So I am not sure whether `EXCLUDE` works here?